# FloatingActionButton showing behind an (extend)toolbar instead of being on top

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying make my layout like this:[first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdqBg.png)

But instead I'm getting this:[second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGsd1.png) (don't mind the buttons being in different colors)

The **FAB**(floating action button) in the first pic is the default android FAB but in the second pic I used this github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton to implement the FAB

**activity_mystackOverflowQuestion.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.coquenim.gradebook.Activities.SubjectActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Stack"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="70dp"
                android:paddingEnd="70dp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Overflow"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@drawable/divider"
            android:dividerPadding="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="00.00"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:id="@+id/subjectAveragee"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="00.00"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:id="@+id/subject_target_grade"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_subject"/>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        fab:menu_labels_style="@style/MenuLabelsStyle"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/jump_from_down"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/jump_to_down"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="0"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#444"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#FFB805"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#F2AB00"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#D99200"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_myStackOverflowQuestion.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_subject"
    tools:context="com.example.coquenim.gradebook.Activities.SubjectActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/currentSubjectName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorBlack"
        />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/currentSubjectName"
        android:childDivider="#00000000"
        />




</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

define elevation of various elements in layout and keep the elevation of Floating action button (fab) greater than all the others

Comment: thats not the answer i'm looking for @jay tandel but thanks anyways.
I can't figure out why using the default FAB works but using an imported one doesn't